# Visual Basic find GPU dedicated memory NVIDIA or AMD

Tags: vb.net, memory, windows-10, gpu, wmi

I am trying to find users dedicated RAM on their GPU. I found code online that is great for finding different GPU properties using WMI, but none of the properties returns anything like "4 GB" for dedicated memory. The closest it has was AdapterRAM, but that returns a huge number that is irrelevant to my purposes.

```
        Dim arr() As String = Nothing
        Dim int As Integer
        Dim objWMIService As Object
        Dim colDevices As Object
        Dim objDevice As Object
        objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")
        colDevices = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select AdapterRAM From Win32_VideoController")

        For Each objDevice In colDevices
            ReDim Preserve arr(int)
            arr(int) = objDevice.AdapterRAM
            int += 1
        Next objDevice

        colDevices = Nothing
        objWMIService = Nothing
        Return arr
```

Is there any other methods, interfaces, ect to find this a users dedicated GPU memory. It should return something like "4 GB"

Comment: I you sure that the "huge number" returned for "AdapterRAM" is not the actual value of 4 GB (a bit more than 4,000,000,000)?

Comment: Yes, my laptop has 7.9 GPU memory which breaks down to 4.0 dedicated and 3.9 shared memory. Whereas, the number returned is 1073741824.

Comment: That number is `Math.Pow(1024, 3) = 1073741824 => 1 GB`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the methods is with DXGI.
For example :

With DXGI declarations : (I cannot paste them, too big...) [VB_DXGI.vb](https://app.box.com/s/qwl8fo52hsxizytisjhv7msgx4kn9m9y)
=>

```
Dim hr As HRESULT = HRESULT.E_FAIL
Dim pFactory1 As IDXGIFactory1 = Nothing
Dim IID_IDXGIFactory1 As Guid = New Guid("770AAE78-F26F-4DBA-A829-253C83D1B387")
hr = CreateDXGIFactory1(IID_IDXGIFactory1, pFactory1)
If ((hr = HRESULT.S_OK) And (pFactory1 IsNot Nothing)) Then
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    Dim pAdapter1 As IDXGIAdapter1 = Nothing
    While (pFactory1.EnumAdapters1(CUInt(i), pAdapter1) <> DXGI_ERROR_NOT_FOUND)
        Dim dxAdapterDesc As DXGI_ADAPTER_DESC = New DXGI_ADAPTER_DESC()
        hr = pAdapter1.GetDesc(dxAdapterDesc)
        Console.WriteLine("Adapter Name: {0}", dxAdapterDesc.Description)
        Console.WriteLine("Dedicated Video Memory : {0}", dxAdapterDesc.DedicatedVideoMemory.ToString())
        Console.WriteLine("Shared System Memory : {0}", dxAdapterDesc.SharedSystemMemory.ToString())
        Console.WriteLine("Dedicated System Memory : {0}", dxAdapterDesc.DedicatedSystemMemory.ToString())
        Console.WriteLine("Total Memory : {0}", (dxAdapterDesc.DedicatedVideoMemory + dxAdapterDesc.SharedSystemMemory + dxAdapterDesc.DedicatedSystemMemory).ToString())
        Dim pOutput As IDXGIOutput = Nothing
        Dim j As Integer = 0
        While (pAdapter1.EnumOutputs(CUInt(j), pOutput) <> DXGI_ERROR_NOT_FOUND)
            Dim outputDesc As DXGI_OUTPUT_DESC = New DXGI_OUTPUT_DESC()
            hr = pOutput.GetDesc(outputDesc)
            Console.WriteLine(vbTab + "Device : {0} ({1}, {2}, {3}, {4})", outputDesc.DeviceName, outputDesc.DesktopCoordinates.left, outputDesc.DesktopCoordinates.top, outputDesc.DesktopCoordinates.right, outputDesc.DesktopCoordinates.bottom)
            j += 1
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(pOutput)
            pOutput = Nothing
        End While
        i += 1
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(pAdapter1)
        pAdapter1 = Nothing
    End While
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(pFactory1)
End If
```